# UDP large packet fragmentation in Python, PyCharm-Windows

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I am now studying networking and reading the book `"Foundations of Python Network Programming"`. I am following the code of UDP packet fragmentation in the book and found that one of `module (IN)` is a default package in linux system while I am using PyCharm in windows to learn the process of socket and networking programming.

I want to ask that:

1. what is the `IN` package is about
2. what other parameter can be used to replace `IN.IP_MTU_DISCOVER, IN.IP_PMTUDISC_DO, IN.IP_MTU` ?

Here is the code provided by the book:

```
import IN, argparse, socket

if not hasattr(IN, 'IP_MTU'):
    raise RuntimeError('cannot perform MTU discovery on this combination of operating system and Python distribution')

def send_big_datagram(host, port):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, IN.IP_MTU_DISCOVER, IN.IP_PMTUDISC_DO)
    sock.connect((host,port))
    try:
        sock.send(b'#'*65000)
    except socket.error:
        print('Alas, the datagram did not make it')
        max_mtu = sock.getsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, IN.IP_MTU)
        print('The big datagram was sent!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Send UDP packet to get MTU')
    parser.add_argument('host', help='the host to which to target the packet')
    parser.add_argument('-p', metavar='PORT', type=int, default=1060, help='UDP port (default 1060)')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    send_big_datagram(args.host, args.p)
```

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._" You should edit your question to remove that part of it asking for book recommendations.

Comment: Just did as you said, any idea on the question though?

Comment: Still, you are asking for a tool recommendation and not stating the problem. What difficulties are you having with the IN module?

Comment: IN module is the default package in Linux System which is not existing in Windows. I am asking for alternative on the module to use in Windows system but not the recommendation of tools. Please look carefully to the description. I did mention about the parameter to be used for replacement of IN module.